# how can i interact in windows (xp, vista, 7) welcome screen or locked screen like a VNC or Dame Ware

Tags: c#, winapi, vnc, winlogon

im trying to make a support software in c#.net like a VNC or Dame Ware and i dont know how to send input event to login or locked screen  in windows (xp, vista and 7)

Comment: +1 good question. I know it has to run as a system service. Somehow the service has to be started on system startup instead of user login. Interacting with the system while locked is easy, if the program is running then it will accept input regardless of being locked. Windows being locked just locks out user input from the keyboard until the lock password is provided. As far as I know anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I have touched C# but here is something to try.  If your application is going to run as a system, and can simulate user input.  Simply send CTRL+ALT+DELETE keys to the console.  That is how VNC/DAMEWARE/HYENA all accomplish the task.  Adversely, they are all written in C or C++.

Don't try to interact with LSASS in an api call to unlock the screen.  Calling the security subsystem to unlock a screen is supposed to be done by keypress and some A/Vs look for apps trying to do it in other ways.